# Reference error express/Not Defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, referenceerror

http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb
I'm trying to run this example, and I'm getting a ReferenceError when I try to run node app.js.

Here's the error:
500 ReferenceError: /home/action/blog/views/index.jade:4 2| h1= title 3| #articles > 4| - each article in articles 5| div.article 6| div.created_at= article.created_at 7| div.title title is not defined

```
2| h1= title
3| #articles
4| - each article in articles
5| div.article
6| div.created_at= article.created_at
7| div.title
title is not defined
at eval (eval at (/home/action/blog/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:176:8), :19:15)
at /home/action/blog/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:181:12
at Object.exports.render (/home/action/blog/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:216:14)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine]             (/home/action/blog/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:243:13)
at View.render (/home/action/blog/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:75:8)
at Function.app.render (/home/action/blog/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:504:10)
at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/action/blog/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:753:7)
at /home/action/blog/app.js:38:13
at /home/action/blog/articleprovider-mongodb.js:43:16
at /home/action/blog/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:159:16
```

It's something in the index.jade file, but I can't seem to figure out where it is going wrong.

Edited to add:
Here's the index.jade file:

```
block content
  h1= title
  #articles
    - each article in articles
      div.article
        div.created_at= article.created_at
        div.title 
            a(href="/blog/"+article._id.toHexString())!= article.title
        div.body= article.body

        extends layout
```

And here's the app.get for the index page:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    articleProvider.findAll( function(error,docs){
        res.render('index.jade', { locals: {
            title: 'Blog',
            articles:docs
            }
        });
    })
});
```

It's passing title in the function, so I'm really not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Post your javascript code that should match this: http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb/2/app.js. You need make sure when you call `res.render` you are passing the "locals" that the template expects, including "title" which should be the article title.

Comment: My app.js is exactly that one; I copied it to be sure. The res.render looks like this:
        res.render('index.jade', { locals: {
            title: 'Blog',
            articles:docs

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I think the express `render` API has changed over time. Try removing the "locals" property and just passing the data directly:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    articleProvider.findAll( function(error,docs){
        res.render('index.jade', {
            title: 'Blog',
            articles:docs
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, removed locals, and now I get this:
500 ReferenceError: /home/action/blog/views/index.jade:6 4| h1= title 5| #articles > 6| - each article in articles 7| div.article 8| div.created_at= article.created_at 9| div.title = article.title body is not defined

Comment: I'm comparing what I have to another app.js and index.jade file, and they seem to be the same. Of course, I could have looked at them so long that they all look alike, which is entirely possible